# How can i solve that relative / absolute issue?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place this text over the image, but it won't work! I alrealdy verified everything in my code from linking css to errors in my code but didn't find anything.

```css
.pai {
  position:relative;
}

.filho {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estudos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pai">
      <img src="bgestudio.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="filho">
        <h1>Qualquer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**strong text**  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsBdx.jpg

Answer (score 2):

You need to make the container div the same width as the image and then the text div fill the container:

```css
.pai {
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block; /* make this div as wide as the image - can be removed if the image is 100% width */
}

.filho {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left: 0; 
  right:0;  /* left and right mean width will be 100%; */
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); /* top 50 and translate mean it is vertically centered */
  
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estudos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pai">
      <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/200/300" alt="">
      <div class="filho">
        <h1>Qualquer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the text where to appear AND set a z-index.

```css
.pai {
  position:relative;
}

.filho {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:center;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Estudos.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pai">
      <img src="bgestudio.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="filho">
        <h1>Qualquer</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```